# Parameter type check for forwarding reference is not working

Tags: c++, templates, forwarding-reference

I am trying to write a template function that will only accept `std::vector` as argument. However what I have come up with works only for normal or lvalue parameters, but not for forwarding reference arguments.

The following code doesn't compile.

```
template <typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if< std::is_same<T, std::vector< typename T::value_type, typename T::allocator_type > >::value>::type >
int f(T && a) {
    return a.size();
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> a;
    f(a);
}
```

However if I replace parameter type of `f` to be an lvalue reference or pass by value type as in:

```
template <typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if< std::is_same<T, std::vector< typename T::value_type, typename T::allocator_type > >::value>::type >
int f(T a) {
    return a.size();
}
```

than it compiles.

Note that, I need to have argument of f a forwarding reference.

What am I missing?

Comment: In forwarding reference version `T` is deduced to be `vector<int>&`, so you cannot use just `T`, you need to discard reference from that type by `std::remove_reference_t<T>`. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/mkA2jK)

Comment: Yes, you are right! @rafix07

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to only accept vectors, then your code can be simplified quite a bit.  Instead of using SFINAE, you can just specify you want a `std::vector` with any type of a parameters.  That would look like

```
template <typename... Pack>
int f(std::vector<Pack...>const & a)
{
    return a.size();
}
```

---

The reason your SFINAE approach doesnt work is that when you pass an lvalue to the function `T` is deduced as a reference type.  Reference types don't work like the type itself when it comes to doing things like

```
typename T::value_type
```

To fix that you need to remove the reference-ness of `T` using `std::remove_reference`.  That would give you a function like

```
template <typename T, typename VecType = typename std::remove_reference<T>::type, typename = typename std::enable_if< std::is_same<VecType, std::vector< typename VecType::value_type, typename VecType::allocator_type > >::value>::type >
int f(T && a) {
    return a.size();
}
```

Comment: Yes, but than I can't make the argument `a` a forwarding reference. I will add this as a note. Thank you.

Comment: @OzgurMurat Just updated the answer.  You don't need a forwarding reference.  You can just take a reference to const, unless you actual code is different?

Comment: This is just for demonstration of my problem. Actual code is different.